# Twoside and page number starting at page 2 with title page

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided

So basically I want twoside (not including the title page) to start at page 1
Rather than 2.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\newpage
page 1
\newpage
page 2
\newpage
page 3
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setcounter{page}{1}` after the first `\newpage` should suffice.

Comment: That is a solution - thank you

Answer (score 1):

`\setcounter{page}{1}` after the first `\newpage` should suffice. – Phelype Oleinik

Comment: But this breaks stuff.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Add `\usepackage{showframe}` and look where the margins are printed. TeX gets really confused.

Comment: Yes I noticed this, what would you recommend?

Comment: Just live with the default. The title is the first page after all.